# How to get smallest difference value from an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, logic

I have an array containing multiple values. Like

```
var values = [1.5, -1, 0 , 5, 5.5, -4];
```

In this case, I want 0, because 0 is the smallest difference from 0.

```
var values = [1.5, -1 , 5, 5.5, -4];
```

In this case, I want -1, because 0 is the smallest difference from 0.

```
var values = [1, -1 , 5, 5.5, -4];
```

In this case, I want +1

Thanks in advance

Comment: How would you do this by hand, with paper and pencil?

Comment: quick question, you why do you want +1 in the first example? Would -1 be just as acceptable?

Comment: @M.Koval In That case i want positive number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reduce to create such function.

```js
function getMin(data) {
  return data.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
    let absR = Math.abs(r), absE = Math.abs(e);
    if (absR > absE || i == 0 || (absR == absE && e > r)) r = e
    return r
  })
}

console.log(getMin([1.5, -1, 0, 5, 5.5, -4]))
console.log(getMin([1.5, -1, 5, 5.5, -4]))
console.log(getMin([1, -1, 5, 5.5, -4]))
console.log(getMin([-1, 1, 5, 5.5, -4]))
```

Comment: If there is any mistake in my question, can you pls edit my question

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function getMin(arr){
  if(arr.length == 0)return undefined;
    var min = arr[0];
    for(var i =0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(Math.abs(arr[i]) < Math.abs(min)){
        min = arr[i];
      }
      else if(Math.abs(arr[i]) == Math.abs(min) && arr[i] > 0)
        min = arr[i]
    }

  return min

}
```

Let me know if this is not what you are looking for and I can change my answer.